# Переключение стилей

Tags: javascript, css

Помогите додумать код. У меня есть 3 блока с текстом и чекбокосм, при переключении блоков я меняю фон и текст, но мне так же надо менять цвет чекбоксов и с этим у меня проблема.

```js
function openButton(buttonName, elmnt, color) {
  // Hide all elements with class="tabcontent" by default */
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("create_form");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Remove the background color of all tablinks/buttons
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    tablinks[i].style.color = "";
    
  }

  // Show the specific tab content
  document.getElementById(buttonName).style.display = "block";

  // Add the specific color to the button used to open the tab content
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
  elmnt.style.color = '#fff';

}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
.tablink {
  width: 10.3125vw;
  height: 3.75vw;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #170738;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Bold', arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: .2vw;
  padding: 1.25vw 1.25vw 0 0;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.tablink input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1vw;
  left: 3vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 1.5625vw;
  height: 1.5625vw;
  border: 0.125vw #815eca solid;
  border-radius: 1vw;
}

.tablink input[type="checkbox"]+label::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1vw;
  width: 1vw;
  margin: 0 0.05vw 0 0;
  background-image: url('img/check_purple.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0.3vw;
}

.tablink input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-position: -0.9vw 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tablink" onclick="openButton('form_telega', this, '#683ec0')" id="defaultOpen">Telegram
  <input id="cfirst" type="checkbox" checkbox hidden>
  <label for="cfirst"></label>
</div>
<div class="tablink" onclick="openButton('form_twitter', this, '#683ec0')">Twitter
  <input id="csecond" type="checkbox" checkbox hidden>
  <label for="csecond" style="left: 4vw;"></label>
</div>
<div class="tablink" onclick="openButton('form_facebook', this, '#683ec0')">Facebook
  <input id="cthree" type="checkbox" checkbox hidden>
  <label for="cthree" style="left: 2.5vw;"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> У меня есть 3 блока с текстом и чекбокосм, при переключении блоков я меняю фон и текст, но мне так же надо менять цвет чекбоксов и с этим у меня проблема.

Вот такой пример, из тех отрывков кода `JS` который вы представили:

```js
function openButton(buttonName, elmnt, color) {
  // Hide all elements with class="tabcontent" by default */
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("create_form");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Remove the background color of all tablinks/buttons
  //tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  /********************************************************
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    tablinks[i].style.color = "";
    //tablinks[i].input[type = "checkbox"] + label.style.border - radius = "";
  }
 
**********************************************************/
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Измененный отрывок кода
  tablinks = document.querySelectorAll('.tablink')
  tablinks.forEach(function(tab) {
    tab.style.backgroundColor = "";
    tab.style.color = "";
    //tablinks[i].input[type = "checkbox"] + label.style.border - radius = "";
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Вот так это должно выглядить, если вы ищите элементы внутри tablink
    tab.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').style.border = ''
    tab.querySelector('label').style.border = ''
    //----------------------------------------------------------------

  })
  // Show the specific tab content
  //document.getElementById(buttonName).style.display = "block";

  // Add the specific color to the button used to open the tab content
  //elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
  //elmnt.style.color = '#fff';

}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
.tablink {
  width: 10.3125vw;
  height: 3.75vw;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #170738;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Bold', arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: .2vw;
  padding: 1.25vw 1.25vw 0 0;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.tablink input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1vw;
  left: 3vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 1.5625vw;
  height: 1.5625vw;
  border: 0.125vw #815eca solid;
  border-radius: 1vw;
}

.tablink input[type="checkbox"]+label::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1vw;
  width: 1vw;
  margin: 0 0.05vw 0 0;
  background-image: url('img/check_purple.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0.3vw;
}

.tablink input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-position: -0.9vw 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tablink" onclick="openButton('form_telega', this, '#683ec0')" id="defaultOpen">Telegram
  <input id="cfirst" type="checkbox" checkbox hidden>
  <label for="cfirst"></label>
</div>
<div class="tablink" onclick="openButton('form_twitter', this, '#683ec0')">Twitter
  <input id="csecond" type="checkbox" checkbox hidden>
  <label for="csecond" style="left: 4vw;"></label>
</div>
<div class="tablink" onclick="openButton('form_facebook', this, '#683ec0')">Facebook
  <input id="cthree" type="checkbox" checkbox hidden>
  <label for="cthree" style="left: 2.5vw;"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваши изменения работают как я и хотел.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем так сложно? Определяете класс `selected`, где перечисляете все нужные стили и при клике снимаете класс у одного элемента и цепляете на кликнутый

```js
(function() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('.tablink');
  [].forEach.call(els, function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.querySelector('.tablink.selected').classList.remove('selected');
      this.classList.add('selected');
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
.tablink {
  width: 10.3125vw;
  height: 3.75vw;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #170738;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Bold', arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: .2vw;
  padding: 1.25vw 1.25vw 0 0;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.tablink input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1vw;
  left: 3vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 1.5625vw;
  height: 1.5625vw;
  border: 0.125vw #815eca solid;
  border-radius: 1vw;
}

.tablink input[type="checkbox"]+label::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1vw;
  width: 1vw;
  margin: 0 0.05vw 0 0;
  background-image: url('img/check_purple.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0.3vw;
}

.tablink input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-position: -0.9vw 0;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #683ec0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tablink selected">Telegram
  <input id="cfirst" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cfirst"></label>
</div>
<div class="tablink">Twitter
  <input id="csecond" type="checkbox">
  <label for="csecond" style="left: 4vw;"></label>
</div>
<div class="tablink">Facebook
  <input id="cthree" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cthree" style="left: 2.5vw;"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что я только учусь ) и на такой способ нашел подробное объяснение.

Comment: @МаксимВоробьев Такие вещи делают именно через динамическое указание класса. Оно и поддерживается проще и код меньше в разы, а значит и ошибок меньше

Comment: Буду знать, спасибо.